# Steps to release flutter and firebase app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am trying to build a release for my app. I have a flutter app with firebase integration.
My app work normally using the Debug key.

However, when I replace my SHA-1 key in the google-services.json, it does not work. I followed the steps bellow:

1. Get the SHA-1 key from Play Developer Console (Apps Signature)
2. Add the SHA-1 key in the Firebase Project configuration
3. Downloaded the google-services.json and put it in my flutter project (in the android\app folder)
4. run the "flutter build apk"

Also, I also tried to use the flutter emulator, but it did not work too.

I can see that it is not working because I cannot authenticate in Firebase.

Finally, my app is already available for Alfa Test in Play Developer Console.

Can you please help me?

Comment: $\alpha = 1+1 \frac{1}{2}$